# deleting or throwing compiler error when a virtual base function is called from a derived class in c++

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I have the following code:

```
 class A
 {
 public:
      virtual void f(int a) = 0;
      virtual void f(int a, int b) = 0;
 };

 class B : public A
 {
 public:
      // do not want f(int a,int b) accessible
      void f(int a);
 };

 class C : public A
 {
 public:
      // do not want f(int a) accessible
      void f(int a, int b);
 };
```

I am aware that purely virtual functions cannot be deleted. Is there any way to disable these functions such that a compile time error occurs if an instance of B tries to call f(int,int) or when an instance of C tries to call f(int)

Comment: Did you mean detecting instead of deleting (in the question title)?

Comment: They are both pure virtual, so they would need to be implemented. that's the compilation error if you try to instantiate B or C.

Comment: What would happen if it is called from `A` interface (`B b; A& a = b; a.f(4, 2);`)?

Comment: The nature of `virtual` is that you can't necessarily know at compile time which function will *actually* be called at a given call site. Edit : Maybe what you want is to implement both `A::f(int)` and `A::f(int, int)` so that they throw, terminate or whatever. That way trying to call it with an instance that doesn't provide it can be detected.

Comment: This just seems wrong. Neither B nor C is really an A here. How about just splitting A into two distinct interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that.  You'd need a more complex class hierarchy.  Something like this:

```
class A
{
public:
  virtual ~A() {}
};

class BaseForB : public A
{
public:
  virtual void f(int a) = 0;
};

class BaseForC : public A
{
public:
  virtual void f(int a, int b) = 0;
};

class B : public BaseForB
{
public:
  void f(int a) override
  {
    // details...
  }
};

class C : public BaseForC
{
public:
  void f(int a, int b) override
  {
    // details...
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put a class between A B and A which implements a private version of the function that is final and not callable by instances of B like this:

```
class A
{
 public:
     virtual void f(int a) = 0;
     virtual void f(int a, int b) = 0;
};

class A_B : public A {
    using A::f;
private:
    void f(int a, int b) final override {}
};

class B : public A_B
{
public:
    // do not want f(int a,int b) accessible
    void f(int a);
};
```